# Android studio, fails to import projects from github

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio, can not import projects from github. My own project pushed from older android studio(8/22), is not imported (year:8/23). All source code is there. Also tried after downloading the repo. Both open and import project was tried and invalidating cache was tried as well. There is no stack trace and only failed message as seen on image below.
Please provide any solution or information to resolve this to import projects.

[image]

Comment: I selected a newer Gradle version from project structure and it started syncing process and worked.